# Append file with two extra colums to a large table?

Tags: paste

I need to paste two columns (in a file) to a very big file with an identical number of columns (length 48554). I have tried this

I have two files with columns separated by tabs. File 1 looks like this:

> Header_1 header_2
>
> 0 23
>
> 1 25

and file 2 looks like this:

> ```
> Header_3 header_4
>
> 2 24
>
> 3 26
> ```

What I want is this:

> ```
> Header_1 header_2 Header_3 header_4
>
> 0 23 2 24
>
> 1 25 3 26
> ```

I have tried paste, e.g. this:

> paste file1 file2 | pr -t -e24

- but I get this:

> ```
> Header_1 header_2
>
> 0 23
>
> 1 25 Header_3
>
> header_4
>
> 2 24
>
> 3 26
> ```

- i.e, the problem is that paste appends the new columns in file 2 to the bottom of the last column in file 1, not added side by side as two extra columns in the +5000 column matrix as I need.

  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Although your delimeter looks more like a space than a tab, `paste` works fine for me.

Alternatives you could try

```
join <(nl file1) <(nl file2) | cut -d' ' -f2-5
```

or

```
awk '{ if (FNR==NR) {F[NR]=$1;G[NR]=$2; next}; {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, F[FNR], G[FNR]}}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately none of these suggestions work. My delimiter in the actual files is indeed a tab, though it may be reproduced as a space here, but either way, the paste command returns identically useless output.

Comment: Your suggestions here: 

> join <(nl file1) <(nl file2) | cut -d' ' -f2-5

gives this output: 

>Header_1 Header_2 
>0 23

Your AWK suggestion gives this output:

>Header_1 Header_2 Header_3 Header_4
>2

I made the files in excel, and saved them as tab-separated txt files - I have verified the hidden codes and tabular separations. It´s simply that nothing is working. :(

Comment: How does your paste oneliner look? No matter how I try it, it either does nothing at all, or merges the top of the columns in file 2 to the bottom of columns in file1.

Comment: just like this `paste file1 file2 | pr -t s24` although the `pr` doesn't seem to do anything on my system......

Answer (score 0):

I can actually make it work in R by importing both files as tables/data frames:

```
 file1<-read.table("file1.txt") 
 file2<-read.table("file2.txt")
```

and then using cbind simply

```
combined.txt <- cbind(file1, file2)
```

but I struggle to comprehend that there could be no simple unix feature that can accomplish the same that worked for me........